# Links not getting created while sending email through asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi i am sending download brochure link in the email but i am receiving only text instead of link in the mail

below is the code from which i am sending the mail

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<html><body><a href='"+Server.MapPath("~/Documents/Brochure.pdf") +"'>Download Brochure </a>");
        sb.Append("<br></body></html>");


        string messageBody = sb.ToString();
        string AdminEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminEmailForEmail"];
        string AdminPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminPasswordForPassword"];
        string Reciepient = Email;
        string subject = "Brochure Download";

        string FromMail = "info@testmail.in";
        string emailTo = Reciepient;
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("testmail.in");
        mail.From = new MailAddress(FromMail);
        mail.To.Add(emailTo);
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Body = messageBody;
        SmtpServer.Port = 25;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(AdminEmail, AdminPassword);
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
        try
        {
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Try replacing `<br>` with `<br/>`

Comment: tried, not working